# C# - Force String.Format to use decimals and NEVER commas

Tags: c#, string.format

Basically I'm realizing that my application is using commas instead of decimals, and i NEVER want to allow this.  Anyone know how I can correct? I can't find one thing via google that is to force decimals, it's all about forcing commas.

```
         return String.Format("{0}f, {1}f, {2}f, {3}f, {4}f, {5}f, {6}f, {7}f, {8}f, {9}f, {10}f, {11}f, {12}f, {13}f, {14}f, {15}f", M.M11, M.M12, M.M13, M.M14, M.M21, M.M22, M.M23, M.M24, M.M31, M.M32, M.M33, M.M34, M.OffsetX, M.OffsetY, M.OffsetZ, M.M44);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of when it's using commas and it should be using decimals?

Comment: Like if someone in the UK starts my application, 1.5654654 will be 1,5654654

Comment: If you don't allow that, it will confuse the hell out of your UK users.  Are you sure that is going to be ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the other overload:

```
return String.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture // <<== That's the magic
,   "{0}f, {1}f, {2}f, {3}f, {4}f, {5}f, {6}f, {7}f, {8}f, {9}f, {10}f, {11}f, {12}f, {13}f, {14}f, {15}f"
,   M.M11, M.M12, M.M13, M.M14, M.M21, M.M22, M.M23, M.M24, M.M31, M.M32, M.M33, M.M34, M.OffsetX, M.OffsetY, M.OffsetZ, M.M44
);
```

This way of calling ensures that the invariant culture is being passed as the format provider to the `String.Format`, ensuring that you get dots for numbers, dollars for currency symbols, English for names of the months and days, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the culture to US English for the String.Format function:

```
String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0}f, {1}f, {2}f", etc)
```